# On Guided Access mode letting device running more than a single app

Tags: ios, guided-access

Is it possible to let user to launch only certain apps by enabling a custom Guided Access from an application?

Guided Access locks iOS device only for a single app but what I want to do is locking the device for certain apps chosen by the user. I did a research but could not find anything about it.

Comment: No I dont believe that is possible. Apple would not let an app control other apps access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it’s not possible by design:

> You can use Guided Access to: Temporarily restrict your iOS device to a single app

Please have a look at this: [Use Guided Access with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612)

Comment: Yes, Guided Access lets only single app access and I do feel like Apple won't let users to disable other apps or only enable certain apps inside an app. But I wanted to be sure.